# jQuery UI 1.9 dialog defaults

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

How can I set default options for the jQuery UI dialog in jQuery UI 1.9.x? Using the old method of

```
$.extend(jQuery.ui.dialog.prototype.options,{
  ...new options...
});
```

doesn't seem to be working, as you can see in this [demo](http://jsbin.com/idugak/3/edit). Thanks for any help!

Comment: Demo uses $.merge, change it to $.extend and it works.